# How can I do a constant watch on MongoDB and update my UI?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to have a constant watch over a **user's notifications in Mongo DB**, which updates on certain actions and keep updating them over my **react frontend** rather than loading them every time a user logs in and im not sure how to.. I'm using **Node and Mongoose models** for checking on my database and requests seem to do the trick but an infinite loop would be resulted when we keep calling it indefinitely..
Can someone suggest anything..?
Im pretty new to this..

Comment: A better architecture would be to give the responsibility to MongoDB to notifiy the changes in collection. try using change stream  
`Applications can use change streams to subscribe to all data changes on a single collection, a database, or an entire deployment ` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/

Comment: Will look into it, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a (micro)service that exposes **HTTP API** and **WebSocket API**.
The **HTTP API** will allow the client application (react) to make **CRUD** request where the **WebSocket** will notify the clients of any updates in real-time.

You can use `WebSocket` in order to push notifications to client see([WebSocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket) or [socket.io](https://socket.io/))

The Idea is that you not need to sample the database for new data. The service will handle the client notification and the database update only when a request is called.

P.S.

I like using [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) (NodeJS framework) because it build exactly for this kind of stuff (but there is always the overhead of learning it)

Comment: Amazing, will look into NestJs too then, thanks! :)